# Secure https encryption for iPhone app to webpage

Tags: iphone, authentication, https

I want to sell an iPhone app, that will house a single web view to a web page, say http://www.myapp.com/webview/ I would like the app to effectively store the credentials required for authentication at the website (ie only someone who has bought the app can view this page)

How else would I have a secure, simple webview on the iPhone, without requiring the user to log in(essentially they buying the app will constitute their authentication to the page)

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You should really accept the answer below.  It is very good.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no absolute way to achieve this goal. If you have a web service that uses a shared credential (one bundled in the application), then it will be possible to reverse engineer that credential. Ultimately it is impossible to ensure that a client running on another machine is "your" client.

There have been many discussions of this. It is not hopeless, only impossible to solve 100% (or even 90%). A simple shared secret over SSL will stop the majority of your attackers without harming your users or costing a lot to develop. It is obfuscation, not security, but cheap and "mostly effective" is much better than expensive and "mostly effective."

If you have a very high-value product, then it may warrant more aggressive (expensive) solutions. All of these solutions include one of two things:

- Authenticating the user rather than the program, or
- Continual vigilance, watching for new attacks and responding with fixes that patch them.

The latter is very expensive and never ends. Make sure it's worth it.

Some other useful discussions:

- [Anti piracy and app identification. iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999029/anti-piracy-and-app-identification-iphone-sdk)
- [Easiest way to limit executable to running on a certain computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337637/easiest-way-to-limit-executable-to-running-on-a-certain-computer)
- [Decompiling Objective-C libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334072/decompiling-objective-c-libraries)
- [Obfuscating Cocoa](http://robnapier.net/blog/obfuscating-cocoa-389)

---

**EDIT** I wanted to point out one thing about my mention of "shared secret over SSL." Remember that if you don't verify the certificate, you are subject to very easy man-in-the-middle attacks. Readily available proxies like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) can do this. The best approach is to make sure that the SSL certificate being returned is signed by *your* root certificate, not just "any trusted certificate." You can reconfigure which certificates are trusted by your application with `SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates()`. [iOS5:PTL](http://robnapier.net/book) covers this technique in Chapter 11 (page 221). I've also wrapped this into a library called [RNPinnedCertValidator](https://github.com/rnapier/RNPinnedCertValidator).

Another good layer is to implement a challenge-response system where the server authenticates that the client has the shared secret without ever putting it on the wire. The Wikipedia article on [Challenge-resonse authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-response_authentication) includes a good explanation of the algorithm.

Comment: Edited to include how to mitigate the problem of SSL sniffing.