# loginless client/server architecture (iOS)

Tags: cocoa-touch, security, web-applications, ssl, authentication

I'm currently in the phase of planing a project involving loginless service.

Users would be identified by an unique device id created on the client (ios).

What are the security concerns? What are the common pattern to prevent attacks?

- sockets would be wrapped with ssl
- create a private certificate to verify client? (what about someone decompiling the binary and obtaining it?)

any thoughts are appreciated

Comment: Also posted on [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/17660/2435).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who is the "attacker" in this scenario? Are you protecting your user from being attacked, or are you treating your user as an attacker? Any scheme that treats the user as an attacker is a DRM scheme, not a security scheme. Security and DRM have completely different problems, and the DRM problem is unsolvable. It can only be mitigated through constant diligence and patches.

Creating a unique id is simple in iOS (see `CFUUIDCreate`), but it is only tied to the specific installation, not the device. If the user deletes the program and you didn't save the UUID somewhere else (say iCloud), then the next time you create a UUID, it will be different.

Users can be authenticated. They have secrets that they hold in their head. General-purpose devices like an iPHone can't be authenticated in a way that cannot be forged by an authorized user. This is a really complicated way of saying that the jailbreak problem is unsolvable and not worth spending much money on trying to solve if you're not Apple. (They have spent much more money on stopping jailbreaks than is likely in your whole development budget, and they can't stop jailbreaks; you're not going to be able to layer-on something better.)

There are ways to weakly identify the device. In particular you can use the MAC address. It's very possible that Apple will take this away in the future. They've taken away the other ways to uniquely identify the device because they're too easy to abuse for spying on the user.

Creating a private certificate to authenticate the *user* is great. To authenticate the program? That's just obfuscation and if your program is worth the trouble, it will be pull out quickly.

This general topic has been discussed many times on SO. See the following for links to several of the discussions. If you have more specific questions not covered before, let us know.

[Best practices for iOS applications security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448632/best-practices-for-ios-applications-security)

Comment: Thanks @Rob, i'm concerned about someone tinkering with the api backend & manipulating users preferences. A possible solution could be to generate a random token as an alibi password on first encounter with the service. UUID + random token should be enough - since i don't need to re-authenticate if the user deletes the app. In this scenario the question is how to determine if a reset of a user is legitimate.

Comment: A UUID already includes a random token, so that's probably sufficient. It's designed to be unique while being difficult to guess. If you're protecting the user's information, then this should be sufficient. I would probably use iCloud to store your UUID so that you don't have to worry about resets. That effectively let's Apple do all the authentication work for you.

Comment: What about users that don't use iCloud?

Comment: There may be no really good way to reliably identify the device in that case. There are similar tools like backups (so you don't lose the setting) and Game Center. But every tool will eventually end in "but they might not have that." For those, you will probably need to individually reset the user via email requests. That usually is much more secure than an automated solution. You just want to keep it to a very infrequent occurance.