# Where to store sensitive data

Tags: ios, security, plist, nsuserdefaults, keychain

What is the best practice to store sensitive(not secure) data on iOS devices?
Where should I store information that user bought something in app? For example where should I store `BOOL showAds` variable if user bought "Remove Ads"?
I do understand that everything breakable, especially on jailbroken devices, I just asking what is the best practice.

My variants:

1. `.plist` in App Documents -- Editable using iFunBox, for example
2. NSUserDefaults -- Same here, I guess
3. Keychain -- best variant in my opinion so far

Comment: You question attracts opinion based answers and I am inclined towards keychain storage. Read more for [security best practices on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448632/best-practices-for-ios-applications-security)

Answer (score 0):

[Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html) is best option to store sensitive data.

### Other than sensitive data below are 2 options :

`Small` `data` can be stored in [NSUserDefault](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as its best way as physical file will not be available for changing data.

`Bigger` `data` can be stored in `database` with `encryption`

Comment: Can you please explain why NSUserDefault variables not accessible for anyone like variables in .plist file? Where does it stored?

Comment: First part of your answer is not true. `NSUserDefault`s are saved in a physical `.plist` file. This file can be found in `{App_Root_Dir}/Library/Preferences` and the file is usually named `com.<yourcompany>.<appName>.plist`. So on a jailbroken device this file can be easily accessed.

Comment: @Amar you could edit it even without jailbrake. I just checked it using iFunBox.

Comment: @user1561346 Thats make my point even stronger, `NSUserDefaults` is not the correct place to store sensitive data. Check out the Q&A I mentioned in my comment below your question.