# Is it possible for an attacker to maliciously modify iOS keychain data?

Tags: ios, security, keychain, misuse

I am storing secure data in the `keychain` that should be maintained only within my app. During app running this data is retrieved to some `variable`. It seems like it is possible to crack my app in order to read that value or even dump the whole `keychain`, but my question is it possible to the "hacker" modify that data i.e. modify at runtime area of `RAM` that holds this `variable` and make my app to update `keychain` with new value? And I also have setter method for that property, which saves it to `keychain`, is it possible to investigate the address of that function and force call my method with custom value?

I already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448632/best-practices-for-ios-applications-security) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181186/secure-https-encryption-for-iphone-app-to-webpage) for best practices, read answer [at Quora](http://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-decompile-iOS-apps-like-Android-apps), [that](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/IOS_Application_Security_Testing_Cheat_Sheet) and [that](http://blog.opensecurityresearch.com/2013/08/analyzing-keychain-contents-with.html) articles, looked for [ios-keychain-analyzer project at GitHub](https://github.com/Foundstone/ios-keychain-analyzer) but there is no mention about changing data, only about reading

Comment: Yes, you can update your own keychain entries. Have you looked at Apples sample code or any of the keychain wrappers available - try cocoapods or GitHub or just google...

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't mean update in usual case - I am aware of that as well. I am talking about cracking my app by someone else in order to call my function with illegal parameters to update keychain entry

Comment: No other app can read your chain entries.  Period!

Comment: @BlackFrog it is not about other apps. For example I can export app to my laptop and investigate the binary with `otool` or connect to the running app with debugger. Question is about modifying keychain by attackers to store incorrect data

Comment: @BlackFrog - This is not necessarily true if the device is jailbroken.  If jailbroken then device can execute code that isn't signed by Apple - this means it may be malicious code installed in the same sandbox as the OP's app. Apple goes to a lot of effort to secure the iOS platform - much of which is described here - http://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf  It isn't clear from that document, but attacking the keychain on the actual device would probably require not only modifications to the app but also the securityd daemon that manages the keychain