# Securing sensitive data like API/Secret keys in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a hard time in searching for the best practice in securing sensitive data in iOS development using Swift.

I already implement some encryption and decryption using RNCryptor in my project. And not sure if it is enough.

I need some recommendation or practices I should do to improve my app's security. Thank you.

Comment: This isn't a programming question and you're asking for a recommendation rather. Please read this guide on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Alright. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Sensitive data should be stored in KeyChain or Secure Enclave(if hardware permits).

[Best practices for iOS applications security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448632/best-practices-for-ios-applications-security)

Comment: That's very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Keychain offers a secure alternative to saving sensitive data, such as
>   user names and passwords, with [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults), [plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html) or similar
>   methods.
>
> As you might already know, NSUserDefaults is simple and effective for
>   saving small, simple bits of data, like NSNumbers or NSStrings, to
>   your device’s file system. But this data is in no way stored securely
>   as hackers can access it pretty easily from the device.
>
> Apple has provided the Keychain Services API to deal with this problem
>   and help developers build apps that safely handle passwords and other
>   sensitive information.
>
> A keychain is defined in Apple’s [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services) as:
>
> Keychain is great because data encryption automatically is taken care
>   of before it is stored in the file system so there is no need to waste
>   time building encryption algorithms.
>
> A keychain in both OS and iOS can be configured to lock. When locked
>   it is impossible to access and decrypt stored keychain items. For iOS
>   the keychain is locked when the device is locked and unlocked when the
>   device is unlocked. Even when it is unlocked, only apps that have
>   created an item can access it, unless configured otherwise.
>
> **Keychain also offers other features like:**
>
> Accessing keychain items
>   across apps. Normally, an app only has access to items it created but
>   configuration can be made to let it access data within a group of
>   designated apps.

[Securing user data with Keychain for iOS](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/securing-user-data-with-keychain-for-ios-e720e0f9a8e2)

Use

Apple’s own Keychain wrapper is called [GenericKeychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) and is available within the sample code in both Objective C and Swift.

## Here are a few Keychain wrappers I recommend:

[SwiftKeychainWrapper by Jason Rendel(jrendel)](https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper)

[SAMKeychain by Sam Soffes for Objective C.](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SAMKeychain)

[Locksmith by Matthew Palmer for Swift. (Check out the video tutorial)](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith)