# How to make my API private but usable by mobile application?

Tags: security, api, http, rest, private

Here is my requirements:

- Usable by any mobile application **I'm** developing

I'm developing the mobile application, therefore I can implement any securing strategies.

- Cacheable using classical HTTP Cache strategy

I'm using Varnish with a very basic configuration and it works well

- Not publicly available

I don't want people be able to consume my API

Solutions I think of:

- Use HTTPS, but it doesn't cover the last requirements because proxying request from the application will show the API KEY used.

Is there any possibility to do this? Using something like a private/public key for example?

Which fits well with HTTP, Apache, and Varnish.

Comment: why do people keep thinking this is possible?  There must be over 1000 questions like this on SO. I am stunned.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no way to ensure that the other end of a network link is your application. This is not a solvable problem. You can obfuscate things with certificates, keys, secrets, whatever. But all of these can be reverse-engineered by the end user because they have access to the application. It's ok to use a little obfuscation like certificates or the like, but it cannot be made secure. Your server must assume that anyone connecting to it is hostile, and behave accordingly.

It is possible to authenticate *users*, since they can have accounts. So you can certainly ensure that only valid users may use your service. But you cannot ensure that they only use your application. If your current architecture requires that, you must redesign. It is not solvable, and most certainly not solvable on common mobile platforms.

If you can integrate a piece of secure hardware, such as a smartcard, then it is possible to improve security in that you can be more certain that the human at the other end is actually a customer, but even that does not guarantee that your application is the one connecting to the server, only that the smartcard is available to the application that is connecting.

For more on this subject, see [Secure https encryption for iPhone app to webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181186/secure-https-encryption-for-iphone-app-to-webpage/9183066#9183066).

Answer (score 4):

Even though it's true there's basically no way to guarantee your API is only consumed by your clients unless you use a Hardware secure element to store the secret (which would imply you making your own phone from scratch, any external device could be used by any non official client App as well) there are some fairly effective things you can do to obscure the API. To begin with, use HTTPS, that's a given. But the key here, is to do certificate pinning in your app. Certificate pining is a technique in which you store the valid public key certificate for the HTTPS server you are trying to connect. Then on every connection, you validate that it's an HTTPS connection (don't accept downgrade attacks), and more importantly, validate that it's exactly the same certificate. This way you prevent a network device in your path to perform a man in the middle attack, thus ensuring no one is listening in in your conversation with the server. By doing this, and being a bit clever about the way you store the API's parameters general design in your application (see code obfuscation, particularly how to obfuscate string constants),  you can be fairly sure you are the only one talking to your server. Of course, security is only a function of how badly does someone want to break in your stuff. Doing this doesn't prevent a experienced reverse-engineer with time to spare to try (and possibly succeed) to decompile your source code and find what it is looking for. But doing all of this will force it to look at the binary, which is a couple of orders of magnitude more difficult to do than just performing a man in the middle attack. This is famously related to the latest snap chat flurrry of leaked images. Third party clients for snapchat exist, and they were created by reverse engineering the API, by means of a sniffer looking at the traffic during a man in the middle attack. If the snapchat app developers would have been smarter, they would've pinned their certificate into their app, absolutely guaranteeing it's snapchat's server who they're talking to, and the hackers would need to inspect the binary, a much more laborious task that perhaps given the effort involved, would not have been performed.

Comment: how about using a line break character?

Answer (score 1):

We use HTTPS and assign authorized users a key which is sent in and validated with each request.

We also use HMAC hashing.

Good read on this HMAC:
http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/