# iOS Secure File Storage Issue

Tags: ios, file, security, storage

I have an iOS app which keeps sync with a database of PDF documents via a RESTful web service.  Basically, the app downloads a few PDF's which I am storing to the file system in my app.

I am using the Library/Caches directory.

```
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)
```

My requirement is to store the files such that the user cannot gain access to them in any way.  When I write the file, I am also providing the option: NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete

```
[decodedFile writeToFile:newFilePath options:NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete error:nil];
```

However, I am still able to access the files through Devices -> Select My App -> Download Container...

I need to configure the app such that the downloaded content cannot be accessed by anything but the app itself.  There must be a way to do this, but I have been unable to find anything...?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solvable problem. If this were a solvable problem, then it would be trivial for Apple to prevent Jailbreaking. They would just write a system validation key in whatever place the user cannot possibly access. The fact that Jailbreaking *is* possible despite Apple controlling every part of the ecosystem should put in perspective your chances of protecting data that you've written to a user's device from that user.

This has been discussed several times, including thoughts on what you actually can do and what's worth doing (nothing is going to be 100%; nothing is even going to be 90%). You can look over the previous incarnations of this question for more. [Secure https encryption for iPhone app to webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181186/secure-https-encryption-for-iphone-app-to-webpage) is a good place to start, since it includes links to several of the others.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I am not concerned with jailbroken instances.  I just want to make it more difficult, or even ideally not possible for non-jailbroken instances.  I understand that there is always a way, but simply connecting the phone to the mac and going into Xcode and having the capability to download the documents in 2 minutes is unacceptable.  There must be a way around this.  I will look at the links you provided...

Comment: If the goal is to just "make it a little harder" then it's pretty trivial (as opposed to "cannot gain access to them in any way" which is impossible). Encrypt the data with a random key you hide in your app. Anyone strongly motivated with moderate skills will be able to break it, but it will work for the cases you describe. I know a lot of teams use RNCryptor this way. https://github.com/RNCryptor

Comment: Actually what I ended up doing is even more trivial...on the server side where the PDF is added, I am adding a password to the document.  In the iOS app, I am using that same password to open the document.  If anyone were to dump the files, they wouldn't know the password.  Problem solved.